# Is there a list of ALL features that are available on some chess clock?

Tags: chess-clocks, equipment

Is there a list of all features that are available on some chess clock?

I played speed chess last week and somebody had an old clock with features I had never heard of before.

So add, delay, both, count up, count down, hourglass,  bell every 10 seconds,  restricted to occurring after some move number,  whatever.

What would be on  a complete list of all chess timer features?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you will find a **complete** list that compares all features between all companies. The closest you might get would be an article that reviews chess clocks, and compares them. I will tell you how I picked my new clock, since it still involves finding the information you are seeking.

When I got back into chess in the last year, I bought a new digital clock since it was time, and I only had some nice old analog clocks. I went to the major manufacturers, DGT, VTEK, and Chronos, and their websites.

Virtually all chess clocks have these basic features today. Using a blitz game of 5-3 as an example, this is how they work:

1. Fischer’s clock – The clock starts at 5:03, runs down to 5:01 and after the move ends up on 5:04.
2. Bronstein’s clock – The clock starts at 5:03, runs down to 5:01 and returns to 5:03 after the move.
3. Time delay – The clock is paused at 5:03 and nothing changes after the move.

For more on this, I pulled this from [this nice article](https://chessentials.com/best-chess-clocks/).

Beyond that, most of the features have nothing to do with chess. They are more along the lines of how many pre-programmed time settings are there, how many personalized time controls you can program in, what is the quality of the materials it is made of, brand reputation, and is it FIDE certified?

Those things, you just have to compare from clock to clock, and there are a lot of reviews out there comparing chess clocks to guide you. You can also look at the manuals to get an idea.

I, ultimately, went with a DGT3000 primarily because it is FIDE certified, and is the clock that you see at all the international events. [You can look at the manual here](https://digitalgametechnology.com/index.php/support1/manuals/clocks/dgt3000), and see a lot more about the features.

Comment: Thanks.   Not sure what value, if any, FIDE certification adds, for most of us in USA,  but I will check your links for more info.

Comment: Well, one of my goals is to get FIDE rated. When I was active, there were only about three FIDE-rated opens per year in the U.S.

Comment: understood.  *IF*  I played again it would only be rapid style not OTBPostal nor blitz.  And I doubt FIDE rates that speed.  Anyway not enough FIDE tournaments in USA for me to go to.

Comment: DGT looks like the best but unclear still on various models now available.  This link confuses me http://i.imgur.com/aWMKmcZ.jpg.  Is the 2010 just a toggle not the metal button sensor?  What is the North American model?  Is that the same as 3000?  I want the features listed in that chart for 2010 on the other style case and buttons not the toggle bar.

Comment: Toggle. https://digitalgametechnology.com/index.php/products/clocks1/79-dgt-2010 The DGT3000 is the newest flagship model, so probably pretty close to the 2010, but a lot newer. I would contact their support with any specific questions: https://digitalgametechnology.com/index.php/support1/customer-service-form

Comment: thanks.  i like the 2010 features but not the seesaw toggle.